# How to detect empty space in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I detect all empty spaces in a string that are the result of more than one space key being entered.

In other words I don't wan to detect this:

```
" "
```

But anything greater than that. For example:

```
"  ", "   ", etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
$regex = '~\s{2,}~';
preg_match($regex, $str);
```

`\s` includes white space, tabs, and new lines. If you want *just* spaces, you can change `$regex` to :

```
$regex = '~ {2,}~';
```

---

If you want to remove extra spaces from a string, you can use:

```
$str = 'hello  there,   world!';

$regex = '~ {2,}~';
$str = preg_replace($regex, ' ', $str);

echo $str;
```

Outputs:

```
hello there, world!
```

Comment: @Bolt I use tildes, some times exclamation points. I never use forward slashes =/

Comment: it's definitely sickening when we're matching forward slashes every day in so many of our checks :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$input = "foo bar  baz   saz";
if(preg_match_all('/\s{2,}/',$input,$matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "  "
    [1]=>
    string(3) "   "
  }
}
```

`\s` represents white-space which include space,vertical-tab, horizontal-tab, return-carriage, new-line, form-feed.

If you want to match just normal spaces, you can use the regex:

```
if(preg_match_all('/ {2,}/',$input,$matches)) {
```